# Time out error while invoking endpoint in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout, endpoint

I am trying to create a AWS Lambda function for my project, which should invoke the endpoint and return prediction of the model as a result.

I attached sagemaker invoke endpoint IAM policy for the attached IAM role to the Lambda funtion. Still,i am getting task timed out error while invoking the endpoint.

I run the lambda function in notebook instance and able to get predictions there, but not getting output in Lambda funtion.

```
import os
import boto3
import json
import csv
# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')


def lambda_handler(event,context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['data']
    #print("payload:"+payload)
    #print("ENDPOINT NAME :"+ENDPOINT_NAME)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                       ContentType='text/csv',
                                       Body=payload)
    print(response)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    
    return result



{
  "errorMessage": "2023-03-04T00:49:45.554Z 38fee791-8b05-49e2-ab69-3035af43e499 Task timed out after 90.09 seconds"
}
```

please suggest to me how to proceed with resolving this error.

Comment: Is your lambda in a vpc? Is your endpoint publicly accessible?

Comment: See [Connect to SageMaker Through a VPC Interface Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/interface-vpc-endpoint.html).

Comment: yes lambda is in a VPC and attached IAM policy for VPC access for lambda IAM role.Endpoint is not publicly accessible

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text.